# Count the number of appointment request and number of available doctors in given timeslot

Tags: sql-server, date, schedule, appointment, timeslots

I have 3 Tables with time slots, doctor's booked schedule, and patients' requests for appointments.
I want to write a query to find the number of doctors available at each time slot and also the number of requests for appointments in each time slot.

Slots (10 mins interval)

| Slot_id | slots |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 09:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 09:10 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 09:20 |

booked_gp_slots (booked timeslots for doctors)

| gp_id | booked_slot_start | booked_slot_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2021-01-01 09:00 | 2021-01-01 10:00 |
| 10 | 2021-01-01 12:00 | 2021-01-01 12:20 |
| 24 | 2021-01-01 09:00 | 2021-01-01 09:40 |

request_slots (booking request for patients)

| patient_id | req_slot_start | req_slot_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 09:00 | 2021-01-01 09:30 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 10:00 | 2021-01-01 10:30 |
| 5 | 2021-01-01 09:00 | 2021-01-01 09:40 |

Sample Output

| Slot_id | slots | GP available | Patient Request |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 09:00 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 09:10 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 09:20 | 3 | 6 |

Since there is no id to connect the tables I am finding it difficult to tally up the counts for available doctors and appointments. My logic would be to check if the doctor's booked slot start time > Slot time and if that is the case add them up. I am not able to aggregate the column coming from the CTE.

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

```
with gp_slot as(SELECT 
gp_id, booked_slot_start, booked_slot_end
FROM 
booked_gp_slots
)

Select 
SUM(CASE WHEN
    (SELECT gp_slot.booked_slot_start FROM gp_slot) > S.Slots THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GP_availibily
FROM Slots
```

Comment: So what have you tried? Why didn't it work? [so] isn't a free coding service, please don't treat it like one. "I want" isn't a question; explain the logic you are trying to achieve and why your attempts have failed. Ask a question.

Comment: If this is a real-world problem, then you need a list/table of all GP's even if they are not already booked at least once.  Your current `booked_gp_slots` table does not list GPs who  are completely open (have zero bookings).